# TypeError: myQRCode.toDataURL is not a function

Tags: react-native

I'm getting this error after I call shareQRCode, TypeError: myQRCode.toDataURL is not a function.
and if I console.log myQRCode I'M getting the svg.

I'm getting this error after I call shareQRCode, TypeError: myQRCode.toDataURL is not a function.
and if I console.log myQRCode I'M getting the svg.

I'm getting this error after I call shareQRCode, TypeError: myQRCode.toDataURL is not a function.
and if I console.log myQRCode I'M getting the svg.

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    Text,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Share,
} from 'react-native';

import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';

const QrCodeshare = () => {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [qrvalue, setQrvalue] = useState('');
    let myQRCode = useRef();


    const shareQRCode = () => {
        myQRCode.toDataURL((dataURL) => {
            console.log(dataURL);
            let shareImageBase64 = {
                title: 'React Native',
                url: `data:image/png;base64,${dataURL}`,
                subject: 'abdulkhaliq.f77@gmail.com', //  for email
            };
            Share.share(shareImageBase64).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        });
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>
                Generation of QR Code in React Native
            </Text>
            <QRCode
                getRef={(ref) => (myQRCode = ref)}
                // ref={myQRCode}
                //QR code value
                value={qrvalue ? qrvalue : 'NA'}
                //size of QR Code
                size={250}
                //Color of the QR Code (Optional)
                color="black"
                //Background Color of the QR Code (Optional)
                backgroundColor="white"
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                Please insert any value to generate QR code
            </Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInputStyle}
                onChangeText={(inputText) => setInputText(inputText)}
                placeholder="Enter Any Value"
                value={inputText}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onPress={() => setQrvalue(inputText)}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>
                    Generate QR Code
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonStyle}
                onPress={shareQRCode}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>
                    Share QR Code
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the `dataURL` correctly for your code. Make sure you've rebuilt your application after installing the package.

Comment: thnks, but still I'm getting the same error

Comment: what do I do to rebuild the application @Rohit

Comment: Uninstall the application from the emulator/device and then install again.

Comment: thnks, the problem is when I open it in web browser but it is working with my iphone expo

Comment: You can try `cd ios` and `xcodebuild clean` for iOS. I have no idea if this will work for expo.